# Logsend fails to send logs to Influx db

Tags: logging, go, influxdb

I am trying to collect centrally all logs of my system. I prefered to go with **logsend and influx db**. I am using a mac book pro and I installed influx db using brew.

I installed logsend locally also and am trying to send a simple log to my influx using the following config,

```
tail -f /var/log/system.log|logsend -influxdb-host "localhost:8086" -influxdb-name log -influxdb-user root -influxdb-password root -influxdb-database Test -influxdb-send_buffer 12
```

My command prompt gets stuck at this,

```
> 2014/12/12 12:40:13 globals.go:16: register sender: influxdb
> 2014/12/12 12:40:13 globals.go:16: register sender: mysql 2014/12/12
> 12:40:13 globals.go:16: register sender: statsd 2014/12/12 12:40:13
> influxdb_sender.go:53: Influxdb queue is starts
```

and in my local influxdb admin site, when I issue the query,

```
select * from log;
```

I get nothing.

Can someone help me debug this? where should I see to check if logsend is connected to influx db, if the ports are correct or for any exceptions?

Thanks in advance,

Karthik

Answer (score 0):

logsend had some errors with sending to influxdb, please download last release by command

`curl -L http://logsend.io/get|sudo bash`

and check

`tail -f /var/log/system.log|logsend -influxdb-name log -influxdb-database Test -regex='(?P<line>.*)'`